# Lengths must match to compare

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, series

How can I match length of DataFrame when comparing indexes?

`df[df.index > df[df.a == 5].index]`
(shape of df is dynamic)

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 10], [5, 10], [0, 10], [5, 10], [0, 10], [0, 10]], columns=["a", "b"])

m = df.index > df[df.a == 5].index
df.loc[m, 'b'] -= np.arange(1, m.sum() + 1)
```

Desired result:

```
   a   b
0  0  10
1  5  9
2  0  9
3  5  8
4  0  8
5  0  8
```

Comment: Can you tell me what "match length of dataframe" means?

Comment: Could you clarify your goal in your question? You code is likely to error since `df[df.a == 5]` is likely going to change the shape of the right side of the inequality.

Comment: Yes, so i want to be able to make the right side the same length so i can do a compare.
Sorry I thought that was self explanatory so I will add an example to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because the length of `df[df.a == 5]` does not match the length of `df`, so following expression:

```
df.index > df[df.a == 5].index
```

is invalid. Both sides has to match in length or one side must be broadcastable, but if the lengths are 5 and 2, that's not possible.

It seems you want group rows according to the position "a" equals 5 and subtract the group number from "b". In that case, you could use `eq` + `cumsum` instead:

```
df['b'] -= df['a'].eq(5).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   a   b
0  0  10
1  5   9
2  0   9
3  5   8
4  0   8
5  0   8
```